# PhpMyAdmin Configuration / Not able to see Input text field

Tags: mysql, configuration, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-12.04, putty

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04. I'm connecting to it with Putty 0.63 beta Port 22.

I've installed mysql and php5 and phpmyadmin with apt-get. And now i want to configure it, but the only thing what's shown on the Terminal is "Package Configuration" and " Configuring phpmyadmin " and nothing else. Normally i should be able to set the password, but this isn't possible.
The same issue occured with MySQL5.5 configuration wizzard.

I have no idea how to fix this or what the reasons are.

Can someone please help me with this issue?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phpMyAdmin doesn't have a password. [It authenticates against](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/intro.html#a-word-about-users) MySQL's user table. The package installation for phpmyadmin asks which webserver(s) to use if you have more than one installed and asks you about creating the [phpMyAdmin Configuration Storage](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#phpmyadmin-configuration-storage) through `dbconfig-common`, but I've never seen it ask any further questions.

When you installed MySQL, it should have asked for a root password. Why it didn't is a mystery, but you can run through the configuration again with `dpkg-reconfigure`. In these cases, I prefer to run it in "low priority" mode where it prompts for pretty much every question and doesn't make any assumptions about my system. You can do that with `dpkg-reconfigure -plow mysql-server-5.5 phpmyadmin`.

Once it's reconfigured, you'll access phpMyAdmin not through SSH (PuTTY is an SSH client), but through your web browser. `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` or `http://localhost/phpMyAdmin` should work (provided you're on the localhost; use whatever your webserver hostname or IP address is instead if needed. I forget if Ubuntu defaults to allowing access from another machine or restricts you to localhost by default).